# How to run multiple commands from a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file that runs a C# console application executable. I need to run the same executable multiple times with a different parameter. When I run the below batch file, it appears to be running only the first command. How can I run all the 3 commands from a single batch file ?
Thank you!

```
@echo off
C:\dev\TestApp\bin\Debug\TestApp.exe "test1"
C:\dev\TestApp\bin\Debug\TestApp.exe "test2"
C:\dev\TestApp\bin\Debug\TestApp.exe "test3"
```

Comment: What does this have to do with C#?

Comment: Please review [MCVE] guidance on posting code - so far code (batch script) shown in the post does exactly what question asks for... At very least show console output (obviously without `@echo off`), but ideally include C# minimal sample as you request C# investigation here.

Comment: If you want all three to run at the same time then use the `START` command. `START "" "C:\dev\TestApp\bin\Debug\TestApp.exe" "test1"` Yes you need the empty quotes,

Comment: `CALL C:\dev...App.exe "test1"`, rinse and repeat might work for you.